# C++ template arguments deduction for rvalues refs vs const lvalue refs

Tags: c++, c++11

I have next code:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct fun
{
    fun(T&&){}
    fun(const T&){}
};

template<typename T>
fun<T> create_fun(T&& val)
{
    return fun<T>(std::forward<T>(val));
}

template<typename T>
fun<T> create_fun(const T& val)
{
    return fun<T>(val);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    const int ci = 2;

    fun<int> a = create_fun<int>(1);
    fun<int> b = create_fun<int>(i);
    fun<int> c = create_fun<int>(ci);

    fun<int> d = create_fun(1);
    fun<int> e = create_fun(i);
    //error: no viable conversion from fun<int&> to fun<int>
    //why is create_fun(T&& val) a better match than create_fun(const T& val)?
    fun<int> f = create_fun(ci);

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please explain me why for non const lvalues the universal reference is a better match?

How may I achieve the same behaviour as the one from `a`, `b` and `c` without explicitly specifying the type to `create_fun`?

EDIT:

I want to force `fun` to be generated with int as parameter for all 3 calls

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct fun
{
    fun(T&&){}
};

template<typename T>
fun<T> create_fun(T&& val)
{
    return fun<T>(std::forward<T>(val));
}

template<typename T>
struct show_type;

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    const int ci = 2;

    show_type<decltype(create_fun(1))>();
    show_type<decltype(create_fun(i))>();
    show_type<decltype(create_fun(ci))>();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the `create_fun(const T& val)` overload? The `create_fun(T&& val)` overload already forwards perfectly...

Comment: const values can't be used with create_fun(T&& val) - I want the resulted class to be generated with template parameter int, not const int&

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `create_fun(i);` with a non-const lvalue `i`, template argument deduction for the two competing overloads results in:

```
fun<T> create_fun(T&& val) ==> fun<int&> create_fun(int& val)  (T = int &)
fun<T> create_fun(const T& val) ==> fun<int> create_fun(const int& val)  (T = int)
```

The first one is a better match than the second by §13.3.3.2 [over.ics.rank]/3.1.6. So the first one is selected.

Instead of using two overloads, you can just use a single universal reference template, and remove reference and `const` from `T` in `create_fun`'s return type:

```
template<typename T>
using remove_cv_and_ref_t = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

template<typename T>
fun<remove_cv_and_ref_t<T>> create_fun(T&& val)
{
    return fun<remove_cv_and_ref_t<T>>(std::forward<T>(val));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca9e11b721c185d0).

Comment: Why not use `std::decay` instead of `remove_cv_and_ref_t` ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Because you might not want the array-to-pointer conversion.

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks for the suggestion! I disabled create_fun for pointers because there are too many problems about the ownership and std::decay make my "real world" code more clean!

Comment: @Felics Yep, if you don't care about the other transformations applied by `std::decay` then it's definitely much shorter to write. (Even better if you have C++14 and `std::decay_t`.)